# Python for Android Mediapipe Import Error: Wrong Build Version

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, mediapipe, python-for-android

I successfully build a python kivy app for android on my Ubuntu system which makes use of opencv and mediapipe. However, when runnning the app I get the following error in logcat:

`ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/mediapipe/python/_framework_bindings.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)`

What I infer from this log is, that mediapipe was build for x86_64 but for the android app it would use the aarch64 build. I tried creating my own p4a recipe but when looking up the pypi builds, there is no aarch64 version.

Further research lead me to similar questions which are all unanswered.
Any idea how to solve this or work around it?